# Listen LWC Event From Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, aura

For example:

In case record page -

I have **Aura Component and LWC Component independently**, user is updating case from LWC Component.
We need to capture that event show the latest update in Lightning Component.

**IN LWC -**

```
const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('caserecordchange', { 
                detail: {caserecord: caserecord}
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
```

In Aura Component - How to capture this ?

Answer (score 2):

It's the event name with "on" prefixed.

```
<c:my-lwc-component oncaserecordchange="{!c.handleCaseRecordChange}" />
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components).

For the moment, the Aura compiler doesn't know what events can be fired from LWC, so be sure not to have any typos, or your event will be missed.

The documentation doesn't mention a way to broadcast to Aura components, but once you fire up from LWC to Aura, you can fire an Application Event. This is mentioned in this [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-for-aura-developers/communicate-with-events) module:

> You can optionally fire a new Aura event to communicate with other Aura components.

This appears to be the only path forward for now. If we get pubsub for Aura, then we'd be able to use that instead.

Comment: I saw this documentation. they embedded LWC component inside Lightning Aura Component. 
In my scenario - 
Its both independent component on detail page.

Comment: @NirmallyaGhosh Thanks for pointing that out. Added more (relevant) details.

Comment: I know how event communication works between two independent lightning component. Just asking how its work between independent LWC and Aura Component.

Comment: @NirmallyaGhosh It doesn't. You need to send the event up to an Aura component, and then that one can fire off an Aura Application Event. There's no pubsub feature for Aura, and LWC doesn't have an Application Event model. You need a "bridge" to cross that divide.

Comment: Is this a part of salesforce lightning aura framework roadmap ? In such scenario how we are gonna solve this.

Comment: @NirmallyaGhosh No idea. For now, this is the solution, an Aura wrapper, or at least a common parent component that can do the translation.

Comment: What do you mean by Aura Wrapper ? We cannot convert existing LWC independent to Aura. is this a roadblock ?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't used this feature yet.

Salesforce now has the Lightning Messaging Service as a **beta** feature for this use-case. Please go thru the following articles for details about how to use it:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/lightning-message-service-developer-preview.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:messageChannel/documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation

Comment: How did you enable this in Developer org or Dev Sandbox ? Its not allowing me to save the component. 
Below Code is not allowing me to save - 
<aura:component>
    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.publishMC}">
    <lightning:messageChannel type="SampleMessageChannel__c"
                              aura:id="sampleMessageChannel"/>
</aura:component>